# finding and grouping max data

Tags: sql, group-by, max

I have a table (Calls) which tells me how long an employee spends on an account.
The data looks as follows:

```
Date            Agent          Talk_Time          Updt_Time
01/10/2013      One            55                 98
01/10/2013      Two            73                 129
01/10/2013      Three          101                84    
02/10/2013      One            65                 99
02/10/2013      Two            87                 122
02/10/2013      Three          130                80    
03/10/2013      One            8                  90
04/10/2013      Two            13                 110
05/10/2013      Three          100                85    
06/10/2013      One            50                 91
07/10/2013      Two            70                 120
08/10/2013      Three          10                 89
```

I am trying to find the MAX talk and update times for the employee.
The other added functionality I require is for it to look at a period of 7 days.
So in the last seven days the data should look like:

```
Agent          Talk_Time          Updt_Time
One            65                 99
Two            87                 122
Three          130                89
```

Comment: `SELECT Agent, Max(Talk_Time), MAX(Updt_Time)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Agent` will give you what you want

Comment: As to the seven day period there is no standard way of doing this. The different database vendors use different functions for that. Here is an Oracle example: where trunc(talk_date) >= trunc(sysdate) - 6

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Its working great. Even with the date - 6 (Thorsten)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its quite simple !!!

```
select agent,max(Talk_time) as talk_time,max(updt_time) as updt_time from table  group by agent
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm a little new to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
select agent,max(talk_time) as talk_time,max(updt_time) as updt_time from calls group by agent
```